# Changing badge style according to status

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code in which I want to change the color of the badge according to the status from database. I planed to make an if statement but I don't get a correct result.

For example color blue if the status is 'Complete' and red if the status in 'Incomplete'

This is my code so far:

```
<span class="badge badge-complete"><?php echo $value['status'] ? 'Complete' : 'Incomplete' ?></span>
```

Screenshot:
[sample badge image](http://postimg.org/image/r27kmdpcd/)

Comment: what exactly do you need?

Comment: I need to display different badges according to status from database

Comment: you can add a php condition to trigger the styles.. like what you are doing with the text inside the span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add seperate class for each status like,

```
<span class="badge badge-complete <?php echo $value['status'] ? 'complete_class' : 'incomplete_class' ?>">
<?php echo $value['status'] ? 'Complete' : 'Incomplete' ?></span>
<style>
.complete_class{
    color:green;
}
.incomplete_class{
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: how about we have 3 or more class?

Comment: simply use the status as class name class="badge badge-complete <?php echo 'class_'.$value['status']; ?>" and add style in your css

Comment: thanks for the response, I am confused about it. how about I add a badge-pending class? then the text value of it is pending? how to that?

Comment: I get it now. thanks. the issue left is changing the text inside of it

Comment: I get all of it now.